# Opensource Virtual box Licence

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

Can I use virtual box that is available in ubuntu software center commercially ?

Comment: I want to use it commerically, to run ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VirtualBox comes with three license versions:

- **Open Source:** this version is free for download and use under the [GPLv2 license](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.en.html). It is the version that is published in the Ubuntu repositories, or from other sources including [Oracle](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). If *distributed* we need to make sure the license requirements are met (e.g. provide access to the source code, allow re-distribution, and more).
- **PUEL:** as soon as we install the Oracle extension pack to an otherwise Open Source VirtualBox we will transform the license into a [personal use and evaluation license](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VirtualBox_PUEL). This means it is no longer possible to use it commercially for free. Only personal use, educational use, or evaluation are granted for free.
- [**Oracle VM VirtualBox Enterprise**](https://shop.oracle.com/apex/product?p1=OracleVMVirtualBoxEnterprise&p2=&p3=&p4=&p5=&intcmp=ocom_virtualization_vmvirtualboxenterprise): this is the paid closed source version available form Oracle providing enterprise support.